# Set Limit on ListView multiple section mode

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an ArrayList of Strings defined called names defined and I add to my ListView object as follows:

I create an Array Adapter and set multiple choice mode in both the Array Adapter and ListView object. This works great, I can scroll and pick multiple objects. But the problem is I want to force the user into being able to pick only 4 items from the ListView. How can I set a restriction?

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,names);
nameList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
nameList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `List` and whenever the `List` exceeds a certain size you could uncheck the first option in the `List` and delete it from the `List` then add the new one or even stop them from selecting another.

So just check in you `onClick` what the size of the list is then decide whether or not you want to process that additionally clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class AccountListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final static String TAG = AccountListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private List<Account> rowItems;

private int selectedItemCounter = 0;

private final int limit;

public AccountListAdapter(Context context, List<Account> items, int limit) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
    this.limit = limit;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final Account rowItem = (Account) getItem(position);

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.account_selection_item, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked && !rowItem.isSelected()) {

                if (selectedItemCounter >= limit) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "can't be more" + selectedItemCounter,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    buttonView.setChecked(false);
                    return;
                }

                rowItem.setSelected(true);
                selectedItemCounter++;
            } else if (!isChecked && rowItem.isSelected()) {
                rowItem.setSelected(false);
                selectedItemCounter--;
            }

        }
    });

    tv.setText(rowItem.getDevId());
    tb.setChecked(rowItem.isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
}
```

tried to improve my code with ViewHolder pattern but failed.
if anyone have better idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had an idea and found a good solution.
I solved the issue "after scroll listview user can also again select more than 3 checkboxes". set `static int count = 0;`

```
if (isChecked) {
    count++;
} else if (!isChecked) {
    count--;
}

if (count >= 4) {
    buttonView.setChecked(false);
    count--;
} else {
    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    contact.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
}
```

And Most imprtant is that add `count=0` in else and `viewHolder.chkContact.setTag(position)` after else;

```
if(convertView == null){   

}
else
{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    count=0;
}
viewHolder.chkContact.setTag(position);
```